# Can I use Office365 Powershell cmdlets to get Sharepoint Online groups and its member names?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, office365

Can I use Office365 Powershell cmdlets to get Sharepoint Online groups and their member names ? If no, what is other possible way to get it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently powershell cmdlet can only be used to manage exchange online. There is no SharePoint Online support nor is there powershell remoting.

Answer (score 2):

The wave 15 of Office 365 has Powershell enabled, only for a few cmd lets. see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364(v=office.15)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late but you can use the project **Client-Side SharePoint Powershell** http://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/ as a PowerShell API to SharePoint Online. The features still need to grow, but you can extend it yourself pretty easy and otherwise just request some features.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read it all through, but it seems like it is possible to manage SharePoint Online with PowerShell.

- [Office 365 windows PowerShell content map](http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/administration/office-365-windows-powershell-content-map.aspx)
- [Manage groups](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh125002.aspx#BKMK_ManageGroups)
- [Use Windows PowerShell to manage Office 365](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh124998.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripts from the Microsoft Script Gallery:

[How to get all the SharePoint Groups in a SharePoint Online Site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-all-the-e594243c)

[How to add users to SharePoint Groups in different SPO sites](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-add-users-to-1d3e69f9)

[How to get all the users in all the SharePoint Groups in a SPO Site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-all-the-users-584284fa)

[How to create a SharePoint Group in a SharePoint Online Site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-create-a-SharePoint-169b2346)

or CodePlex solution:

https://sharepointonlineautomationcmdlets.codeplex.com/